# Displaying primary key and not null columns for all Tables in a schema

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and I'm trying to get all the info in a schema like table names, columns (all columns associated with that table), IsNullable, primary key (if columns is PK it should display yes if it is not then NO)

I tried this query:

```
select 
    a.table_name, a.column_name, a.is_nullable,
    case  
       when b.CONSTRAINT_NAME like '%_PK' then 'PRIMARY_KEY'
       else 'NO'
    end as CONSTRAINT_NAME 
from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a 
left outer join 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE b on a.table_name = b.table_name
                                          and b.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'Primary key' 
where 
    a.table_name = 'Orders'
```

But I am not getting the correct output for primary key column. Getting like `PRIMARY_KEY` for all the columns in the table.

Comment: Refer the dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. You can run a select query there.

Comment: Already derived table name,column names, is nullable columns from that table.....only issue with primary key column....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix 1 :

Add `COLUMN_NAME`  also into the join condition.

Fix 2 :

The result you might be looking for can be got by joining with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` table and identifying primary key using `CONSTRAINT_NAME` is not a wise choice

A better approach is

```
SELECT A.TABLE_NAME,
       A.COLUMN_NAME,
       A.IS_NULLABLE,
       CASE
           WHEN  C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
           THEN 'YES'
           ELSE 'NO'
       END AS CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE B 
    ON A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME AND 
    A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C ON 
        B.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME AND 
        B.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND 
        B.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AND 
        B.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE -- C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND 
    A.TABLE_NAME = 'Orders'
```

Comment: excellent, this is what am looking for, thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @GeethaAnand, glad I could help